# Grails URL mapping for resources that don't exist

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, gsp, url-mapping

I have a `fizzbuzz.gsp`, and I have a `FizzBuzzController` with an `index()` method that renders this GSP:

```
class FizzBuzzController {
    def index() {
        render(view: "fizzbuzz", model: getModel())
    }

    def getModel() { ... }
}
```

Normally, to get the HTML associated with the `fiizbuzz.gsp` file, I would make a call to `http://myapp.example.com/fizzbuzz`.

I have a unique situation where I now **need** my Grails app to serve requests for HTML file URLs like so `http://myapp.example/fizzbuzz.html`.

Does Grails provide any way to map incoming request for `http://myapp.example/fizzbuzz.html` to `http://myapp.example.com/fizzbuzz`? That way, the client-side could request an HTML file, but that would still serve back the correct GSP/HTML file from the server-side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that is different ways. If you are using Grails 2.3 or above you can use `redirect` in `UrlMapping.groovy` as:

```
"/fizzbuzz.html"(redirect: "/fizzBuzz")
```

which dictates to "*If you see fizzbuzz.html in url, then redirect to the `index` action of `fizzBuzz` controller*"

or you can also use it explicitly as

```
//index is the default action therefore specifying action in the map is optional
"/fizzbuzz.html"(redirect: [ controller: "fizzBuzz", action: ''index' ])
```

or you can duplicate the mapping as

```
"/fizzbuzz.html"(controller: "fizzBuzz")
```

In either of the case it would invoke the action method instead of looking for any static resource.